# What is the value we get on printing an array in cpp?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner to c++, I wrote this in my code:

```
int *ptr;
int arr[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

cout << arr << endl;
```

This outputs to '0x61ff00'.
What does the value mean ?
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the address of the first element of the array `arr` converted from the array.

Comment: The array decays into a pointer, and that pointer gets printed. So, yes, it's the address of the array's first element. Now, if that had been a `char` array then the array's contents would have been printed as a zero terminated string, because `char` pointers get special treatment by streams.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay)

Answer (score 5):

There is no standard overload for arrays. There is however an overload for `const void*`. The array decays to a pointer to first element, which further implicitly converts to `const void*`. The result is an implementation defined textual representation of the address that is the value of the `const void*` object.

Memory addresses are essentially numbers. 0x is a prefix for hexadecimal numbers.

---

Following doesn't apply to the example, but does apply to some other arrays: If the array element is `char`, then the behaviour of the character stream is different, because there is an overload for `const char*`. In that case, the behaviour is to treat the array as a null terminated string, and the result is the string contained within the array. String literals are null terminated arrays of `char`.

Example:

```
std::cout << "Hello, World!";
```

Output:

```
Hello, World!
```

If the array doesn't contain the null terminator, then the behaviour of the program is undefined. Don't ever insert such array into a character stream.